# Calculate age standardised rates by sub-group with confidence intervals in R

Tags: r, confidence-interval, rate

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame (
  time = rep(c("2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014"),4),
  age = rep(c("40-44", "45-49", "50-54", "55-59", "60-64"),4),
 weight = rep(c(0.38, 0.23, 0.19, 0.12, 0.08),4),
 ethnic = rep(c(rep("M",5),rep("NM",5)),2),
 gender = c(rep("M",10), rep("F",10)),
 pop = round((runif(10, min = 10000, max = 99999)), digits = 0),
 count = round((runif(10, min = 100, max = 999)), digits = 0)
)
df$rate = df$count / df$pop
```

I want to calculate the direct age standardised incidence rates, where incidence rate = count/pop), and confidence intervals for these; for each subgrouping. So I would have a standardised rate for each combination of time, gender, ethnicity, age. Is there a way to do this in R?

I have tried using the function `ageadjust.direct` from the R package {epitools}, as so:

```
age_adjust_test <- ageadjust.direct(count = df$count, pop = df$pop, 
                                rate = df$rate, stdpop = df$weight)
```

The output from this is an overall adjusted rate, confidence intervals, and crude rate. Is there a way to get this output by each sub-group?

Comment: The package is epitools

Comment: thanks, what is the sub-group you refer to.  Is it by ethnic, gender and age?

Comment: I want an incidence rate for every combination of age, time, ethnicity, and gender. So for gender = M, ethnic = M, age = 40-44, and year = 2010; for gender = M, ethnic = M, age = 40-44, year = 2011 etc etc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can do a group by `summarise` into a `list` and then `unnest` the `list` components into separate columns

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
   group_by(time,age, ethnic, gender) %>% 
   summarise(age_adjust = list(ageadjust.direct(count = count,
            pop = pop, rate = rate, stdpop = weight))) %>%
   mutate(age_adjust = map(age_adjust, as.data.frame.list))  %>% 
   unnest
# A tibble: 20 x 8
# Groups:   time, age, ethnic [10]
#   time  age   ethnic gender crude.rate adj.rate     lci     uci
#   <fct> <fct> <fct>  <fct>       <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1 2010  40-44 M      F         0.00763  0.00763 0.00709 0.00820
# 2 2010  40-44 M      M         0.00763  0.00763 0.00709 0.00820
# 3 2010  40-44 NM     F         0.0281   0.0281  0.0257  0.0306 
# 4 2010  40-44 NM     M         0.0281   0.0281  0.0257  0.0306 
# 5 2011  45-49 M      F         0.0145   0.0145  0.0136  0.0155 
# 6 2011  45-49 M      M         0.0145   0.0145  0.0136  0.0155 
# 7 2011  45-49 NM     F         0.0425   0.0425  0.0399  0.0453 
# 8 2011  45-49 NM     M         0.0425   0.0425  0.0399  0.0453 
# 9 2012  50-54 M      F         0.0116   0.0116  0.0109  0.0124 
#10 2012  50-54 M      M         0.0116   0.0116  0.0109  0.0124 
#11 2012  50-54 NM     F         0.00708  0.00708 0.00607 0.00821
#12 2012  50-54 NM     M         0.00708  0.00708 0.00607 0.00821
#13 2013  55-59 M      F         0.0251   0.0251  0.0232  0.0271 
#14 2013  55-59 M      M         0.0251   0.0251  0.0232  0.0271 
#15 2013  55-59 NM     F         0.00733  0.00733 0.00678 0.00792
#16 2013  55-59 NM     M         0.00733  0.00733 0.00678 0.00792
#17 2014  60-64 M      F         0.0101   0.0101  0.00944 0.0109 
#18 2014  60-64 M      M         0.0101   0.0101  0.00944 0.0109 
#19 2014  60-64 NM     F         0.00916  0.00916 0.00852 0.00984
#20 2014  60-64 NM     M         0.00916  0.00916 0.00852 0.00984
```

Comment: Thanks. I get this error when I run this code: "Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Column `adjust` must be length 1 (the group size), not 4"

Comment: When I run this code on my full dataset, it works, but it creates one new variable called "age_adjust" with the values for this variable being a list of all four output values (rate, adjusted rate, LCI, and UCI). Is there a way to get four new variables, one for each of rate, adjusted rate, LCI, and UCI?

Answer (score 4):

Here's a handy data.table way, one line is enough.

```
library(data.table)
library(epitools)
# convert df to data.table
setDT(df)
# define subgroups
group_by<-c('time','age', 'ethnic', 'gender')

# ageadjust.direct by subgroups. The trick is to include as.list()
df[, as.list(ageadjust.direct(count = count, pop = pop, rate = rate, stdpop = weight)), by=group_by]
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply use `by` to subset dataframe by one or more factors, then pass the subset into your function. Here, `by` will return a list of dataframes using the function values as shown on [docs page](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/epitools/versions/0.5-7/topics/ageadjust.direct). Outside `by`, you can then bind all dfs into one final dataframe with `do.call(rbind,...)`.

```
age_adjust_test_list <- by(df, df[,c("time", "gender", "ethnicity", "age")], function(sub) {
                            tmp <- ageadjust.direct(count = sub$count, pop = sub$pop, 
                                                    rate = sub$rate, stdpop = sub$weight)

                            data.frame(time = max(sub$time),
                                       gender = max(sub$gender),
                                       ethnicity = max(sub$ethnicity),
                                       age = max(sub$age),
                                       crude_rate = tmp[[1]],
                                       adj_rate = tmp[[2]],
                                       lower_CI = tmp[[3]],
                                       upper_CI = tmp[[4]])
                           })

final_df <- do.call(rbind, age_adjust_test_list)
```

NULLs will show for combinations that are not represented in dataframe. So consider filtering out as needed:

```
age_adjust_test_list <- Filter(function(x) !is.null(x), age_adjust_test_list)
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Is there a way to get this output as a table or dataframe?

Comment: See update building a list of dataframes. I am using [docs](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/epitools/versions/0.5-7/topics/ageadjust.direct) page assuming a list of vectors are returned from method.

Comment: Thanks. When I run this code, I get the following error: "Error in tmp$crude.rate : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors " I think I need a different way to subscript the temporary object. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: I got this to work by changing `crude_rate = tmp[[1]], adj_rate = tmp[[2]]` etc - by indexing the temporary object (tmp) correctly

Comment: Got it. So they were not named vectors as docs alluded to. It was all a guess as I do not have the package installed. Edited accordingly. Glad it worked out. Happy coding!